# How to validate with JSON Schema a single element of an array with conditional if/then?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I'm having some troubles trying to evaluate an attribute of the evaluated json and apply a required attribute to the specific element in the array.

I have this schema.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "format": "json",
  "required": [
    "products"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "products": {
      "type": "array",
      "maxItems": 999,
      "minItems": 1,
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "required": [
          "sku",
          "description"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "sku": {
            "type": "string",
            "maxLength": 50
          },
          "barCodeValue": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "vin": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "description": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "allocations": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
              "type": "object",
              "required": [
                "purchasedUnits",
                "facilityAllocationId"
              ],
              "properties": {
                "purchasedUnits": {
                  "type": "number",
                  "multipleOf": 0.001
                },
                "facilityAllocationId": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              },
            },
          },
          "status": {
            "type": "object",
            "required": [
              "id",
              "name"
            ],
            "properties": {
              "id": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "name": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "allOf": [
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "products": {
            "contains": {
              "properties": {
                "status": {
                  "properties": {
                    "id": {
                      "const": 7
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "products": {
            "items": {
              "required": [
                "allocations"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And this json to be evaluated:

```
{
  "products": [
    {
      "sku": "112233",
      "vin": "1234",
      "description": "Bed",
      "status": {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Status 7"
      },
      "allocations": [
        {
          "purchasedUnits": 6,
          "facilityAllocationId": "153"
        },
        {
          "purchasedUnits": 12,
          "facilityAllocationId": "108"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "sku": "332211",
      "vin": "4321",
      "description": "Table",
      "status": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Status 2"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The problem is that when I change the **products.status.id** to 7, the evaluation of the **allocation** attribute goes for all the json's array.
As in this case the element that has the ***status.id = 7*** has an ***allocation*** attribute but the schema is throwing an error.

And I need that evaluation and required is applied only to the element that has the coincidence.
[image]

This is the url to the schema and the example.
[schema](https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/8dJwvmIB)

Basically I need that the *required* ***allocations*** attribute be applied only to the coincidence on the element that matches the ***products.status.id*** to 7 and doesn't evaluate all the other elements on the array.